# Alert - странная кодировка если мы берем строку от сервера

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Когда просто пишу

```
Alert("один");
```

Выводит

```
один
```

Когда беру текст с сервера (.NETCore)

```
Alert("@await Utilites.GetLabel()");
```

Выводит

```
&#x420;&#x443;&#x441;&#x441;&#x43A;&#x438;&#x439; &#x442;&#x435;&#x43A;&#x441;&#x442; English text
```

Метод на сервере

```
public static async Task<string> GetLabel()
{
  return "Русский текст English text";
}
```

Почему в Alert русская кодировка успешно работает только, если задавать текст напрямую, а если брать его с сервера, то всё наворачивается? B при этом на английском все ок? И как это починить?

Добавлю - в страничке кодировка utf-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Потому-что данные с сервера экранируются дабы предотвращать XSS атаки. Кирилица экранировалась в  html entities, если тот текст вставить в html там уже будет обычная кирилица.

Comment: @dresser и как перевести html entities в формат, корректный для alert?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript - вот тут есть вариант

Comment: А что такое `Alert`? Ваш какой-то метод?